# How to solve this issue

Tags: multisite, errors

Showing this message " Redirecting you to "Redirecting you to https://example.com/exapmle" " after clicking on any link in my Wordpress site

Comment: Turn off all plugins and switch to a default theme, to start with. That'll eliminate plugin/theme problems as possible culprits. Also, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/367861/edit) to provide more context: What was changed just before the issue started? Were you working on any specific code?

Comment: Also, by "any link" do you mean anything on the front end, anything in wp-admin, or both? Once you've disabled plugins and switched to a default theme, also make sure to clear all layers of caching (your browser's cache, host/server caching) before you check to see if the problem is resolved.

Comment: **A quick tip for getting great answers**: Many experts are busy people. Help them get to all the facts as soon as possible (without asking follow up questions) and you will get many more answers. Check [our guide to asking good questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need to.